# Make text appear entirely inside div

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm trying to have my text inside the 'container' div show up entirely but it seems to get cut off? .. It works if there is only a bit of text but if the text is more than 1 page it will cut it off.. Also the page seems to load very long because of the background image (defined in stylesheet.css) How do I fix this the best ? Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'zcool';
 src:  url('fonts/zcool.ttf') format('ttf');
 local:  url('fonts/zcool.ttf') format('ttf');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
}

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-image: url("img/bg.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {  /* when screen size is < 768px apply the following styles */
  body {
    padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-image: url("img/bgm.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}

ul#horizontal-list {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header {
 background-image: url(img/j.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {  /* when screen size is < 768px apply the following styles */
  .header {
    background-image: url("img/johnswork-mobile.svg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  }
}

.body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 color: black;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 /*background-color: grey;*/
}


.johnswork {
 background-image: url(img/johnswork.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.content {
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90%;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-right: double;
 border-left: double;
 box-shadow: 0px -21px 28px 7px rgb(162, 27, 27);
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {  /* when screen size is < 768px apply the following styles */
  .content {
    margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90%;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-right: double;
 border-left: double;
 box-shadow: 0px -21px 28px 7px rgb(27, 125, 162);
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
  }
}


.social {
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}


.me {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 3%;
 height: 100%;
}


.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 72%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto auto 50px;
}

#copyright {
 display: table;
}


#cpy{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-m.css" media="handheld" />-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
  <meta name="description" content="My Personal Portfolio">
  <title>John's Work</title>
</head>

<body>


 <nav class="navbar">

  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>

 </nav>


 <header class="header">
 
 <!-- background defined in stylesheet.css-->
  
 </header>

  <section class="body">
   <section class="content">
   
   <section class="johnswork">
   <!-- background defined in stylesheet.css-->
   </section>
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac ipsum non diam faucibus dignissim. Praesent a dolor tincidunt, rutrum diam ut, convallis orci. Maecenas eleifend, sapien id blandit rutrum, enim augue cursus magna, vitae varius orci nulla eu arcu. Cras ultrices condimentum libero nec vulputate. Praesent id ante dignissim, congue elit id, iaculis eros. Aliquam lacus quam, facilisis et pulvinar quis, hendrerit varius erat. Duis feugiat imperdiet lobortis. Ut et faucibus dui. Integer quis bibendum tortor, at mattis dolor. Sed id lacus nec nisi iaculis blandit. Duis nec ligula orci. Quisque tincidunt, orci id tincidunt consequat, eros erat dictum urna, vel ultricies sem nisl eu nunc. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse at malesuada magna, in suscipit purus.

   Fusce facilisis pharetra dui, ut cursus orci maximus non. Cras nec magna ac odio ornare ornare. Proin id commodo eros. Phasellus dui est, malesuada non mi sit amet, fringilla rhoncus ante. Phasellus non elit id est cursus malesuada. Maecenas accumsan erat in urna pulvinar, sit amet egestas felis facilisis. Nullam tincidunt porta nulla, a consectetur sapien venenatis in. Phasellus elementum est sit amet sem accumsan tincidunt. In semper vulputate risus, sed sollicitudin libero consectetur eget. Curabitur pulvinar eleifend augue. Sed facilisis ligula sed arcu vulputate tempus.

   Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut mi nisi, mattis sed est a, luctus aliquet metus. Integer fringilla, massa nec laoreet dapibus, odio sem convallis massa, a vestibulum tellus mi in massa. Sed at vulputate velit, id sagittis sem. Vestibulum ac libero massa. Vivamus et libero vel orci auctor sodales a a quam. Vivamus semper tortor eget lacus euismod, non dignissim tellus feugiat. Donec tincidunt nisi at ornare ullamcorper. Nulla at mi nulla. Phasellus ligula ante, vehicula sit amet mauris et, consectetur mollis odio.

   Donec massa risus, ultricies et enim quis, vestibulum consectetur arcu. Nunc sed convallis dui, sagittis imperdiet metus. Sed non ultrices velit. Nullam arcu sem, varius non pulvinar id, convallis eget erat. Nam porta tincidunt lorem, non venenatis sapien hendrerit vitae. Suspendisse nec est leo. Nunc commodo, lectus nec facilisis laoreet, ex velit dapibus dui, et aliquet lacus est non velit. Vestibulum nisl velit, tempor vel lacus at, ultricies pellentesque nisi. Mauris velit tortor, aliquam a magna eget, efficitur fringilla erat. Praesent massa nisl, maximus sit amet viverra in, varius vel urna.

   Pellentesque eget leo vitae neque dictum egestas at ullamcorper nulla. Aenean lacinia venenatis metus, in faucibus dolor sollicitudin eget. Sed volutpat sit amet urna vel molestie. Donec dignissim velit tortor, a blandit ligula commodo dapibus. Vestibulum ac dolor facilisis mauris maximus mattis. Nullam vitae libero ut ligula sodales accumsan et vel dui. Quisque dapibus, lacus accumsan interdum efficitur, tellus augue maximus ipsum, quis ultricies dolor justo in diam. Pellentesque id lobortis diam. Suspendisse mollis eget orci eu auctor. Nullam porttitor arcu mi, nec varius magna viverra quis. Fusce eleifend sodales turpis et hendrerit.
   
   </section>
  </section>

 <footer class="footer" id="copyright" style="text-align:center">
  <div id="cpy">&copy; DA COSTA JOAO (2019)</div>
 </footer>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also if I wanted to have an image float alongside the text and positioned on the left, how would I do this best ? Thanks!

Comment: And it shouldn't have a scrollbar on the right of the 'content' div..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the text cutting off, the below css seems to fix it without cutting off the image.

```
.body{
    height: auto;
}
```

As for the background image, it may be the file size. I usually use https://compressor.io/ to reduce my file sizes while maintaining image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Seems to fix the problem of the text getting cut off.

Comment: Yes but then the -> body {
 background-image: url("img/bg.png");
}

will get cut off

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want an image with text going around it. You can try this out!

```css
  .image-container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px 5px 0px;
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374811/pexels-photo-374811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  </div>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac ipsum non diam faucibus dignissim. Praesent a dolor tincidunt, rutrum diam ut, convallis orci. Maecenas eleifend, sapien id blandit rutrum, enim augue cursus magna, vitae varius orci nulla
    eu arcu. Cras ultrices condimentum libero nec vulputate. Praesent id ante dignissim, congue elit id, iaculis eros. Aliquam lacus quam, facilisis et pulvinar quis, hendrerit varius erat. Duis feugiat imperdiet lobortis. Ut et faucibus dui. Integer
    quis bibendum tortor, at mattis dolor. Sed id lacus nec nisi iaculis blandit. Duis nec ligula orci. Quisque tincidunt, orci id tincidunt consequat, eros erat dictum urna, vel ultricies sem nisl eu nunc. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse at malesuada magna,
    in suscipit purus. Fusce facilisis pharetra dui, ut cursus orci maximus non. Cras nec magna ac odio ornare ornare. Proin id commodo eros. Phasellus dui est, malesuada non mi sit amet, fringilla rhoncus ante. Phasellus non elit id est cursus malesuada.
    Maecenas accumsan erat in urna pulvinar, sit amet egestas felis facilisis. Nullam tincidunt porta nulla, a consectetur sapien venenatis in. Phasellus elementum est sit amet sem accumsan tincidunt. In semper vulputate risus, sed sollicitudin libero
    consectetur eget. Curabitur pulvinar eleifend augue. Sed facilisis ligula sed arcu vulputate tempus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut mi nisi, mattis sed est a, luctus aliquet metus. Integer
    fringilla, massa nec laoreet dapibus, odio sem convallis massa, a vestibulum tellus mi in massa. Sed at vulputate velit, id sagittis sem. Vestibulum ac libero massa. Vivamus et libero vel orci auctor sodales a a quam. Vivamus semper tortor eget lacus
    euismod, non dignissim tellus feugiat. Donec tincidunt nisi at ornare ullamcorper. Nulla at mi nulla. Phasellus ligula ante, vehicula sit amet mauris et, consectetur mollis odio. Donec massa risus, ultricies et enim quis, vestibulum consectetur arcu.
    Nunc sed convallis dui, sagittis imperdiet metus. Sed non ultrices velit. Nullam arcu sem, varius non pulvinar id, convallis eget erat. Nam porta tincidunt lorem, non venenatis sapien hendrerit vitae. Suspendisse nec est leo. Nunc commodo, lectus
    nec facilisis laoreet, ex velit dapibus dui, et aliquet lacus est non velit. Vestibulum nisl velit, tempor vel lacus at, ultricies pellentesque nisi. Mauris velit tortor, aliquam a magna eget, efficitur fringilla erat. Praesent massa nisl, maximus
    sit amet viverra in, varius vel urna. Pellentesque eget leo vitae neque dictum egestas at ullamcorper nulla. Aenean lacinia venenatis metus, in faucibus dolor sollicitudin eget. Sed volutpat sit amet urna vel molestie. Donec dignissim velit tortor,
    a blandit ligula commodo dapibus. Vestibulum ac dolor facilisis mauris maximus mattis. Nullam vitae libero ut ligula sodales accumsan et vel dui. Quisque dapibus, lacus accumsan interdum efficitur, tellus augue maximus ipsum, quis ultricies dolor
    justo in diam. Pellentesque id lobortis diam. Suspendisse mollis eget orci eu auctor. Nullam porttitor arcu mi, nec varius magna viverra quis. Fusce eleifend sodales turpis et hendrerit.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: well not exactlu around it but I want the image to float on the left and the text nicely justified on the left side of the pic and if you scroll down on the whole page the image will scroll with it